# Build from a bitbucket repository using tfs 2010?

Tags: git, tfs, msbuild

Our small team just made the change from hosting our code using TFS version control to git. We're hosting our git repos on bitbucket. I've been looking for the past couple of days if we could continue using the TFS 2010 build server, but when I try to create a new build the only path I'm allowed to choose from is the path of the previous TFS version control server. My question is how, if at all possible; can I point our TFS build server to a bitbucket repository?

Comment: TFS 2010 cannot, but 2015 yes, but in this latter case why using Bitbucket if 2015 has built-in support for Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Giulio Vian mentioned, TFS 2010 doesn't have the capability of building from a bitbucket repository. But TFS 2015 has.

In the New build system of TFS 2015, it supports building from external Git service.

[image]

> Instead of TFS 2010, you can use [Visual Studio Team Service](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/),
>   which also has the capability of building from an external Git
>   repository. VSTS is free for 5 users, you can start it for free.

Comment: Thanks, I think we'll try using the Visual Studio Team Service, we are a small team so I think it will work well.